# Converting structures on heap to c from c++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, heap-memory

The question is, write a function called `card_factory`, which takes no parameters and returns a pointer to a Playing_Card structure.
The Playing_Card structure is to be declared as follows:

```
struct Playing_Card
{int rank;
int suit; };
```

Inside the factory function, allocate a new Playing_Card structure on the heap. Populate the rank member with a random value of between 1 and 13 inclusive. Populate the suit member with a random value of between 0 and 3 inclusive. Return this new Playing_Card structure to 
the caller.

From the main function call card_factory five times. Store the result of each call in an array of 
Playing_Card pointers.
Write another method called print_playing_card which takes in a pointer to a 
Playing_Card, and prints as follows:

> Printing playing card:
>   Rank: Queen
>   Suit: Clubs

Where suits are represented as follows: 0 = diamonds, 1 = hearts, 2 = clubs, 3 = spades.
And the ranks as follows: 1 = Ace, 11 = Jack, 12 = Queen, 13 = King, 2 to 10 are the values 2 to 10.
Ensure before `main()` exits, that it cleans up the memory allocations by freeing the appropriate heap allocations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Playing_Card {

int rank;
int suit;
};

void print_playing_card(Playing_Card *ptr) {
cout << "Rank: ";
switch (ptr->rank) {
case 1:
cout << "Ace\n";
break;
case 11:
cout << "Jack\n";
break;
case 12:
cout << "Queen\n";
break;
case 13:
cout << "King\n";
break;
default:
cout << ptr->rank << "\n";
}
cout << "Suit: ";
switch (ptr->suit) {
case 0:
cout << "Diamonds\n";
break;
case 1:
cout << "Hearts\n";
break;
case 2:
cout << "Clubs\n";
break;
case 3:
cout << "Spades\n";
break;              
}

cout << endl;
}
Playing_Card* card_factory() {
Playing_Card *temp = new Playing_Card;
temp->rank = rand()%13 + 1;
temp->suit = rand()%4;
return temp;
}

int main() {

Playing_Card *arr[5];

// Allocate memory on heap
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) arr[i] = card_factory();


// Print the cards
cout << "Printing Playing Cards:\n\n";
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) print_playing_card(arr[i]);

// Free the memory allocated on heap
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) delete(arr[i]);

// exit
return 0;
}
```

I have written this code and I need it to be in c programming language and not in c++, could anyone help me with the conversion?

Comment: I recommend an array of text rather than using `switch` statements.  Much more efficient.  You can also extend the concept to function pointers for handling menus.

Comment: So, instead of writing C++ (and not very idiomatic C++ at that), why did you not just write it in C?

Answer (score 1):

cout becomes printf

new becomes malloc

delete becomes free

Declare any automatic variables at the beginning of the block.

edit:  Add `struct` in front of all `Playing_card` references.

I think that covers your port.

Comment: The OP may also want to add input and output methods to the `Playing_Card` structure, such as overloading `operator>>` and `operator<<`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews.  He wants to go the other way (to c not c++)

Comment: @RussSchultz could it be possible if you edit my code or type it for me? i tried it on my system by it wont compile as there are too many errors

Comment: @RussSchultz ok but can you atleast tell me how am i supposed to declare" temp"?.

Comment: Add 'struct' in front of all references to 'Playing_card'

Comment: "Declare any automatic variables at the beginning of the block" is a bad idea in any ISO C. It was only needed in K&R